# Editing meta shortcut on nano text editor

Tags: terminal, text-editor, nano

Is there any option to change the meta `M-` shortcut on nano text editor?

Im working with a Mac, and I wanted to change the meta shortcut for comfort reasons. I'm actually using the `esc` key but will love to change it to my preference.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebind *individual* keybindings by editing your [`~/.nanorc` file](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html#REBINDING%20KEYS) to include keybindings. Unfortunately, nano only supports `^`, `M-` and `F` as modifiers, so it would be difficult (not to mention tedious) to fit all `M-` keys elsewhere.
Instead, it might be simpler to rebind the key in your terminal program, or use an external hotkey remapping program. I have no expertise with the latter on Mac, but you could start looking [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x).